# css is lost when form is submitted

Tags: html, css, forms, loading, contacts

Form

```
<form method="post" action="php/contactengine.php">
<ul>
  <li><label for="Name">Name:</label></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" /></li>
</ul>
<ul id="Surname">
  <li><label for="Surname">Surname:</label></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Surname" id="Surname" /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><label for="Town">Town:</label></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Town" id="Town" /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><label for="Tel">Mob/Tel:</label></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Tel" id="Tel" /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><label for="Email">Email:</label></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><label for="Message">Message:</label><br /></li>
  <li><textarea name="Message" rows="30" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" class="reset-button" /></form>
```

Engine

```
 <?php

$EmailFrom = "enquiry@madisonjacob.co.uk";
$EmailTo = "james@madisonjacob.co.uk";
$Subject = "Website communication - MadisonJacob";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));
$Surname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Surame']));
$Town = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Town']));
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel']));
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));

// validation

$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contact-error.php\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Town: ";
$Body .= $Town;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
if(isset($_POST['Surame']) && $_POST['Surname'] == '') {
  $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
}

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contact-thanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contact-error.php\">";
}
?>
```

...
Having issues with the contact form just going to the error page without any css showing.  Think I've broken it somewhere too using some suggestions (my fault i'm sure).
Do I have to force a refresh on initial load with a counter so that it doesn't keep on reloading (if so how is best to do this please)?
If it's just that I'm not using the best code above then please correct me thanks.
Surname is a hidden field (hidden by css) to stop bots using the form.
All help much appreciated.

Comment: any errors / 404 on css files in your dev tools?

Comment: I can't see a reason for that...Does it happen also the same on the error page?

Comment: use the full path for the css file

Comment: Try to redirect users using the Location header and not using <meta> tag

Comment: Could you please post the full page code? Do you use header.php and include('header.php') or not?

Answer (score -1):

Could you please post your full code? Rest i feel you must use

document.location.href = 'contact-thanks.php';

for redirection.

Comment: would that be instead of the whole 'print' line or just within the speech marks after print?

Comment: you can just include the script tag into your php code within the print or echo. And instead making a meta redirect you must do it with javascript. like : echo "<script type="text/javascript">"; echo "document.location.href=(''contact-thanks.php")"; echo "</script>";